# Sharing axes in matplotlib plot_surface

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

So I have some 3d surface: [image: 3d surface]

in which I have an x coordinate of time, a y coordinate of wavelength, and a z coordinate of intensity - the units don't really matter for my question.

I have another metric, which also can be plotted with time as an x coordinate:

[image: An image with an x coordinate of time]

What I am wondering, and I don't see anything in the docs about this, is if I can share axes in a similar way to 2d plots such that the 'temperature ramp' figure is plotted on the xz plane at y = 400 (or the back wall) in a similar manner to how a contour projection would be plotted, but with a new fourth axis, shared with z, indicating temperature.

Does anyone have a clue about doing this?

Comment: I'd first look at the "twin" axis option, not sure if it works with 3D contours

Comment: the twinx() option throws an error 'YAxis' object has no attribute 'tick_left' unfortunately.

Comment: I found this discussion which may or may not be relevant to my problem (I am uncertain exactly what the person actually was attempting to do): http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/double-axis-3D-plot-td44335.html